# Way to determine files from folder in java exceeding specific size

Tags: java, file, io

I have requirement wherein i dont want to iterate and check length of each file , is there any way other than iterating to determine the files whose size exceed than specified limit

Regards

Answer (score 0):

First of all: You can't check all file lengths without inspecting the size of each file in your folder. At some point you **have** to iterate over them.

However, you can use very simple code for that, using [Apache Commons IO's FileFilters](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/SizeFileFilter.html):

```
File dir = new File(".");
//use 'listFiles(...)' instead of 'list(...)' in order to get a File[]
String[] files = dir.list( new SizeFileFilter(1024 * 1024, false) );
for ( int i = 0; i < files.length; i++ ) {
  System.out.println(files[i]);
}
```

The SizeFileFilter filters the list of all files in the given directory, the resulting String[] contains the filenames of the files that are smaller than 1024*1024 bytes.